# Using scale in CSS Animation

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

I'm trying to use CSS3 animations to scale up a div.  However, I want to keep the top side of the div where it's at.  So I only want the bottom part of the div to scale up.  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show a mock-up image of the before and after? I don't know if you want to make the bottom edge of the div bigger than the top (and form some kind of trapezoid, or just keep the top border of the div in the same place, and make the div taller (or smaller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `-transform-origin` , by default at 50% 50%

More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin